# Right-angled triangle inside circle, chord as hypotenuse

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

> A 3-4-5 right triangle lies inside the circle $2x^2+2y^2=25$. The triangle is moved inside the circle in such a way that its hypotenuse always forms a chord of the circle. Find the locus of the vertex opposite to the hypotenuse.

Well I'm sort of confused on this question. I tried using polar coordinates and trig-bashing but its not giving suitable results. I am intuitively guessing that the locus will be a circle but I'm not sure.

Comment: And what are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: Great question to explore with dynamic geometry software.

Comment: It's definitely a circle.

Comment: @Arby Concentric with original circle.

Comment: Consider a chord of 5 units in a circle, centre at origin,  of radius 5/√2. Half angle subtended by center of circle  at M by the chord. Sin ($\theta$) = 2.5 / (5/√2) = 1/2 √2, I.e. $\ theta $ = 45°, i.e. angle subtended at M is 90°. M is located on the Thales circle over chord, so is the vertex of triangle, base 5, sides, 3,4. Let the chord move along the circle, the constellation remains the same, with the distance of the triangle vertex to the centre M constant. Left: calculate distance from vertex to M(0,0), this is the radius of the circle , centre at M(0,0) along which the vertex moves.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that the distance of the chord from the center of the circle is $5/2$, and the height of the triangle with respect to the chord is $12/5$. Moreover, this height divides  the chord into two segments of lengths $9/5$ and $16/5$. Hence the distance of the right-angle vertex from the center of the circle is the hypotenuse of the right triangle of sides $16/5-5/2=7/10$ and $5/2-12/5=1/10$, that is $\sqrt{7^2+1^2}/10=1/\sqrt{2}$.
Therefore the desired locus is a circle concentric with the original circle with radius $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
The circle has radius $\frac5{\sqrt2}$. Suppose we position the triangle and circle such that

- the triangle hypotenuse is centred at the origin and parallel to the $x$-axis, forming a chord of the circle
- the circle centre and right-angled vertex are in the upper half-plane

Then the circle centre has coordinates $\left(0,\sqrt{\left(\frac5{\sqrt2}\right)^2-\left(\frac52\right)^2}\right)=\left(0,\frac52\right)$, while the right-angled vertex's coordinates are not much harder:
[image]
In other words, the right-angled vertex's coordinates are $\left(\frac7{10},\frac{12}5\right)$. The distance between the two vertices of interest, which remains the same no matter how the triangle is arranged in the circle, is thus
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac7{10}-0\right)^2+\left(\frac{12}5-\frac52\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt2}2$$
and the locus of the right-angled vertex is thus $x^2+y^2=\frac12$.

Comment: I'm getting very confused here, sorry. You say the circle center has coordinates $(0,\frac 5 2)$ but both circles, the original and the locus, are centered at the origin are they not?

Comment: @Arby The circle is translated here to simplify the working.

Comment: I can see that now, but since there are now 3 circles in the problem with your introduction of a translated one, it gets very confusing just to reference 'the circle' in my opinion.

Comment: @Arby No, the original circle becomes the translated circle, and I introduce the locus circle only at the very end. There should be no ambiguity here.